# The correct way to pass pointers to functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, arguments

Afternoon All,
I've written a chunk of code which isn't working correctly. What I'm trying to do is pass an array as an argument to a function so when I return from the function I can continue using the array. My below code gives me a SEG fault or an 'Illegal Instruction' Error, it's random. If someone could give some adive if this is how one passes an array to a function.

```
struct message sMsg[nodeCount];
/* get contents into an array */
getFile(file, sMsg);

void getFile (FILE *file, struct message sMsg*) {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It will be more correct** to declare the function the following way specifying the third parameter

```
void getFile (FILE *file, struct message *sMsg, size_t n );
```

and call it as

```
getFile( file, sMsg, nodeCount );
```

Comment: +1, `sMsg` only says where the array starts, you need use another piece of information to say how much elements are in there

Comment: You might like to add an explanation like *Kos*'s to your answer. However: +1 to point out the probable root cause of the OP's issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
void getFile (FILE *file, struct message sMsg*)
```

to

```
void getFile (FILE *file, struct message *sMsg)
```

But this will not SEGFAULT, its a compile time error.

Comment: So as the OP seems to be observing a run-time error, pointing out the "typo" in the code snippets whould have suited better as comment.